# Why does best_in_place editor not work with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I am trying to get best_in_place to work with my application. The best_in_place works for me by default in my view:

```
<%= best_in_place @user, :first_name %>
```

The moment I import jquery-ui using the script below, it stops working, i.e. it appears as simple text.

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<%= best_in_place @user, :first_name %>
```

The html source does not change either

```
<span class='best_in_place' id='best_in_place_user_1_first_name' data-url='/users/1' data-object='user' data-attribute='first_name' data-type='input'>Ed</span>
```

Any idea how to make jquery-ui and best_in_place co-exist?

My controller, just in case:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@user = User.find params[:id]

 respond_to do |format|
  params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:notice] = "Profile updated"
    format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully updated.') }
    format.json { respond_with_bip(@user) }
    sign_in @user
  else

    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.json { respond_with_bip(@user) }
    sign_in @user
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: To clarify: is the issue related to adding jQuery, or _jQuery-ui_? The script you're referencing is jQuery, but you're citing jQuery-ui.

Comment: thanks for point out- my bad, meant to say jquery, no ui

Answer (score 0):

This is just speculation, but it may be the case that jquery is being included multiple times - either by the best_in_place gem, the jquery gem or elsewhere in asset pipeline land. Check your javascript console in chrome for errors and include them here.

Comment: I get the following error on the applicatoin.js file when I add the jquery. (the error does not appear without it) 

'Uncaught TypeError: Object [object object] has no method best_in_place'

Comment: Yep, sounds like you have the issue I described. I believe that you might have had jquery included by a gem before you tried to manually include Jquery.

Try running the code without including jquery yourself? Maybe it'll work!